# jsf commandButton managedBean action redirect to 404 page

Tags: spring, jsf, managed-bean

I have my ManagedBean
TodoService.java

```
package com.medkhelifi.tutorials.todolist.services;

import com.medkhelifi.tutorials.todolist.models.dao.ITodoDao;
import com.medkhelifi.tutorials.todolist.models.entities.Todo;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TodoService implements ITodoService {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "ITodoDao")
    private ITodoDao ITodoDao;

    @Override
    public void addTodo(Todo todo) {
        ITodoDao.addTodo(todo);
    }

    public void setITodoDao(ITodoDao ITodoDao) {
        this.ITodoDao = ITodoDao;
    }
}
```

And I have my form to add new data
index.xhtml

```
   <!-- extra code coes here -->     
   <b:column colMd="6">
            <div class="todolist not-done">
                <h1>Todos</h1>
                <h:form>
                    <b:inputText type="text" class="form-control add-todo" placeholder="Todo Title"/>
                    <b:inputTextarea type="text" placeholder="Description" />
                    <b:dateTimePicker placeholder="todo Date" format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"/>
                    <h:commandButton action="#{todoService.addTodo(null)}" class="btn btn-success" value="Add"/>
                </h:form>

                <hr/>
                <ul class="list-unstyled" >
                    <ui:repeat value="#{TodoDao.getCurrentUserTodos()}" var="todo"  >
                        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!todo.done}">
                            <li class="ui-state-default">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="" />#{todo.title}</label>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </ul>
                <div class="todo-footer">
                    <strong><span class="count-todos"/></strong> Items Left
                </div>
            </div>
        </b:column>
  <!-- extra code coes here -->
```

When I perform my add button I'm redirected to the same page with 404 status.
There is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<web-app    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
            version="3.0">

    <!-- DEFINE APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT  -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- DEFINE JSF SERVLET MAPPING   -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FACES SERVLET</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FACES SERVLET</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- DEFINE WELCOME PAGE -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!--    SPRING SERVLETS -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:/conf/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!--    SPRING CONTEXT -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:conf/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!--        SPRING SECURITY FILTER -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <!-- Add this dispatcher to handle /j_spring_security_check url -->
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I use also Spring security:
applicationContext-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll()"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" access="permitAll()"/>

        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
        <form-login
                login-page="/login.xhtml"
                default-target-url="/index.xhtml"
                authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml?error"
                login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
                username-parameter="input_username"
                password-parameter="input_password" />
        <logout
                logout-success-url="/login.xhtml"
        />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
            <password-encoder hash="bcrypt"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

And when I debug, the method TodoService.addTodo is never called, I hope I explained my problem well.
There is my stack:
Spring 4.2.2-Final
JSF 2.2.17

Comment: The method is never called since `#{todoService.addTodo}` does not match a method in your bean. And most likely you have an exceptionhandler in place, otherwise you'd have gotten an error in your screen (and there still is one in the log I assume)

Comment: @Kukeltje I updated my method to match a method in my bean and same result.

Comment: What about the other part of my comment? And please create a [mcve]. There could still be way to many cause that I don't want to start guessing about. And please check all in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value

Comment: You've right @Kukeltje after few hours of searching I found the issue, I missed some details that I didn't mention in my post, I'll add those details and also the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours of searching I found the issue:
I missed to add csrf security hidden input to my form since I use csrf protection in my Spring security.

index.xhtml

```
   <!-- extra code coes here -->     
   <b:column colMd="6">
            <div class="todolist not-done">
                <h1>Todos</h1>
                <h:form>
                    <b:inputText type="text" class="form-control add-todo" placeholder="Todo Title"/>
                    <b:inputTextarea type="text" placeholder="Description" />
                    <b:dateTimePicker placeholder="todo Date" format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"/>
                    <!-- I missed to add this line -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
                    <h:commandButton action="#{todoService.addTodo(null)}" class="btn btn-success" value="Add"/>
                </h:form>

                <hr/>
                <ul class="list-unstyled" >
                    <ui:repeat value="#{TodoDao.getCurrentUserTodos()}" var="todo"  >
                        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!todo.done}">
                            <li class="ui-state-default">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="" />#{todo.title}</label>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </ul>
                <div class="todo-footer">
                    <strong><span class="count-todos"/></strong> Items Left
                </div>
            </div>
        </b:column>
  <!-- extra code coes here -->
```